# Question regarding Separation of Variables for Laplace's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, voltage, gauss-law, differential-equations

***Laplace's Equation is given by  $$\nabla^2V=0$$***

***Laplacian Operator in Spherical Coordinates is*** $$\dfrac{1}{r²}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r}(r²\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial r})+\dfrac{1}{r²sinθ}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial θ}(sinθ\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial θ})=0.$$

Now Griffith's considers the Radial Part of the Equation and gives a general solution.

$$\dfrac{d}{dr}(r²\dfrac{dR}{Dr})=l(l+1)R$$

has a general solution $$R(r)=Ar^l +\dfrac{B}{r^{l+1}}.$$

How does he arrive at this equation?

Comment: Just plug the $R(r)$ in the equation and check that's fulfilled.

Comment: Separation of variables is standard mathematical procedure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations

Comment: @Frederic Thomas Thomas ,but how did he arrive at the solution here ?

Comment: @Roger Vadim ,but how did he arrive at the solution of the Ordinary Differential Equation in r ?

Comment: The radial part is $2^{nd}$ order DE, one needs 2 solutions: one is $R1=r^l$, the other one $R2=r^{-(l+1)}$. To make sure that's the case, compute: $(r^2 R1'(r))' = l (r^2 r^{l-1})' = l ( r^{l+1})'  = l(l+1) r^l = l(l+1) R1(r)$. Fine.  Then you do the same for the second  $(r^2 R2'(r))' = -(l+1)(r^2 r^{-(l+2)})' =  -(l+1)(r^{-l})' = (-l)(-1(l+1)) r^{-(l+1)} = l(l+1)R2(r)$. It's a linear DG, so if R1 and R2 are a solution, AR1 + BR2 is also a solution.

Comment: @HarryCase: well, the radial DG is not complicated, one just makes a guess and checks it out.  One could start with  $(r^2 R'(r))' =x R(r)$, and during the calculation process one finds that $x$ should be $l(l+1)$. One could argue for a general solution one needs a solution that is smooth (or even zero) at zero and another one which is zero at infinity. Then you can guess already R=R1 or R=R2 (see my comment above). If you want a mathematical procedure, may be you ask on Math Exchange.